# Can't send more than 160 byte to module by Bluetooth on Android?

Tags: bluetooth

Unable to send more than 160 bytes to a Bluetooth (BLE) module from my Android application, I am sending data from my modified Fastble Android app to a microchip RN4871 Bluetooth. I'm running BLE in transparent UART mode. After connecting to the module, In Android application, calling a notify function and then a write function to send packets in 20-byte chunks.

However, after 160 bytes, the Android application does not send any more data; by increasing MTU, we can send up to 600 bytes but no more.

What we basically observed is that after we modified the Fastble android code, the notify descriptor has a NULL value, which we are unable to correct because I did not understand the cause.

**this is the calling code for notify and write function, "hex" variable is the string to write.**

```
<code>
  setCharaProp(2);
        ((CharacteristicOperationFragment) fragments.get(2)).showData(hex);
        setCharaProp(1);
        ((CharacteristicOperationFragment) fragments.get(2)).showData(hex);
        setCharaProp(2);

<code>
```

**the below code is to notify and write**

```
<code>
 public void showData(String hex) {
      final BleDevice bleDevice = ((OperationActivity) getActivity()).getBleDevice();
      final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = ((OperationActivity) getActivity()).getCharacteristic();
      final int charaProp = ((OperationActivity) getActivity()).getCharaProp();
      String child = characteristic.getUuid().toString() + String.valueOf(charaProp);

      for (int i = 0; i < layout_container.getChildCount(); i++) {
          layout_container.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
      if (childList.contains(child)) {
          layout_container.findViewWithTag(bleDevice.getKey() + characteristic.getUuid().toString() + charaProp).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else {
          childList.add(child);
          View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.layout_characteric_operation, null);
          view.setTag(bleDevice.getKey() + characteristic.getUuid().toString() + charaProp);
          LinearLayout layout_add = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_add);
          final TextView txt_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
          txt_title.setText(String.valueOf(characteristic.getUuid().toString() + getActivity().getString(R.string.data_changed)));
          final TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
          txt.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());

          switch (charaProp) {
          
              case PROPERTY_WRITE:
                  {
                      View view_add = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.layout_characteric_operation_et, null);

                      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(hex)) {
                          return;
                      }
                      BleManager.getInstance().write(
                          bleDevice,
                          characteristic.getService().getUuid().toString(),
                          characteristic.getUuid().toString(),
                          HexUtil.hexStringToBytes(hex),
                          new BleWriteCallback() {

                              @Override
                              public void onWriteSuccess(final int current, final int total, final byte[] justWrite) {
                                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          addText(txt, "write success, current: " + current +
                                              " total: " + total +
                                              " justWrite: " + HexUtil.formatHexString(justWrite, true));
                                      }
                                  });
                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onWriteFailure(final BleException exception) {
                                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          addText(txt, exception.toString());
                                      }
                                  });
                              }
                          });
                      layout_add.addView(view_add);
                  }
                  break;
                  
              case PROPERTY_NOTIFY:
                  {
                      View view_add = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.layout_characteric_operation_button, null);
                      if (my_notify_ctl == 1) {
                          my_notify_ctl = 0;
                          BleManager.getInstance().notify(
                              bleDevice,
                              characteristic.getService().getUuid().toString(),
                              characteristic.getUuid().toString(),
                              new BleNotifyCallback() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void onNotifySuccess() {
                                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {
                                              addText(txt, "notify success");
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }

                                  @Override
                                  public void onNotifyFailure(final BleException exception) {
                                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {
                                              addText(txt, exception.toString());
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }

                                  @Override
                                  public void onCharacteristicChanged(byte[] data) {
                                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {
                                              addText(txt, HexUtil.formatHexString(characteristic.getValue(), true));
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }
                              });
                      } else {
                          BleManager.getInstance().stopNotify(
                              bleDevice,
                              characteristic.getService().getUuid().toString(),
                              characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                          my_notify_ctl = 1;
                      }
                      layout_add.addView(view_add);
                  }
                  break;
                  
          layout_container.addView(view);
      }
  }
  <code>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like your application does not respect flow control

Comment: Maybe you could post your code so we can identify your bug?

Comment: Edited the post with code, please check it.